# REST service: ASP.NET Core versus .NET WCF in embedded "self-hosted" scenario

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-core

I am having difficulties to understand proper usage of the new ASP.NET Core in an embedded self-hosted scenario within a Windows service.

I needed a small self-hosted REST service, embedded within a .NET Windows service. 
I found samples to succeed with working REST functions using WCF and to also wrap .NET Windows service code around that. My C# WCF-based REST micro service works fine and the resulting code looks short and easy to maintain.

Missing accomplished so far, but....
...after that, I found out that there are newer features hidden in NET, meant to be primarily used to host REST services.
WCF is said to be old fashioned, the simpler alternatives being ASP.NET "Web API" and its successor, the brand new ASP.Net Core.

Now I feel unsure whether it would be better idea to go with ASP.Net Core in the future.

Since I would need embedded self-hosting without IIS, it looks like I will e.g. need [Kestrel](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#kestrel) for running REST services as a self-hosted service

It seems doable as well this way instead using WCF, but to me the boiler plating around it looks more complicated than the unpopular WCF.
There seems to be more stuff to take care on the developer side and more files to handle and more stuff to do when deploying/operating it.

I totally agree so far that ASP.Net Core looks like the better choice when going for a full-blown modern REST-service IIS/ASP.NET solution.

But from what I've seen so far I think, ASP.Net Core may not be the best choice for an embedded self-hosted REST micro service within a Windows service - to me the disregarded old WCF looks a lot simpler for that.

Am I missing something? Are there maybe simpler deployment scenarios for ASP.Net Core? (within the requirement scope of wanting an embedded, self-hosted REST service within a .NET program)

Comment: First of all, ASP.NET5 has been renamed to ASP.NET Core and released as RTM; dnx was removed - now we have dotnet CLI. Regarding self-hosting - start from reading about about available Servers https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html, especially about Kestrel: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#kestrel

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I was using "WebServiceHost" with WCF which seems to use http.sys. According to this list, ASP.NET core has Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener, which is effectively http.sys aswell. So this would be the preferred choice for a simple embedded REST service host when using ASP.NET Core/MVC6